# How can i get cell text/data information of a table header tagged with "th" using watir

Tags: watir

i have a html code looks like this...

```
<tr>
  <th width="40">Header</th>
</tr>
```

how can i get the index number and text of this particular cell

I have tried following code.

```
BROWSER.table(:class,"head").row(:index,2).cells.each_with_index do |cell,index|
            puts cell.text

     end
```

---

Thanks a lot for quick reply...

but when i use cell.index it shows

undefined method `index'

and i couldn't print the text as well when i want to print something with "" tag,but this code is ok when i print text of a cell with "" tag

Comment: What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: the way this is asked it is very hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  perhaps if you could explain at a higher level why you need to find that header, and why the index of the header is important?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should only add this:

```
puts cell.index
```

Comment: the way he's got it working, isn't 'index' it's own object inside his do loop?   perhaps  "puts index"  would work?

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provided, you need to use

```
puts index
```

The error you are getting is because there is no method called .index defined for the cell object.

The way .each_with_index works is that it allows you to pass two things into the block, the object extracted from the collection (in this case 'cell') and a second variable which is the index of the object within the collection.   In your case you called this variable "index" although it's often very common to just use "i" for an iterator or index value.

So rather than trying to call .index (a method that does not exist) on the cell object, you need to just use the name of the second variable being passed into the do loop

```
BROWSER.table(:class,"head").row(:index,2).cells.each_with_index do |cell, i|
  puts i
  puts cell.text
end
```

BTW: I suppose it might be possible to create such a method, but the thing is that it's very hard for an object to know its own index, since the index is relative to some outer container.  A cell for example might be the 15th cell in a table, the 7th cell of a row, and the the 24th cell in one div but the 42nd cell within another div.  So if you were to call .index on such a cell, how would it know WHICH of those indexes (or many others) it should return?